Check Box failing to Visually update in WPF C# Xaml
I'm working on a program that will take an existing list and allow users to select an item individually or with a Select all Check box.
When the select all checkbox is ticket,  there is no visual update change, however when the users scrolls down the relevant check boxes are filled in, the empty ones when scroll up are updated as well.
Functionally the check box option works fine, but Visually it's failing and the users may find that as a bug.
I checked the bindings and all is correct.
  <DataGrid x:Name="displayDataGrid"
        Grid.Row="1"                          
        RowHeight="20"
        Focusable="True"
        Margin="5"
        BorderBrush="DarkGray"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPrintLabel}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding PrintLabelCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" >
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox     x:Name="CheckBoxCheckAll" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"                                                                                               
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckAll,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                Checked="CheckBoxCheckAll_Checked"
                                Unchecked="CheckBoxCheckAll_Unchecked" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox     x:Name="headerRowCheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                Unchecked="headerRowCheckBox_Unchecked"
                                Checked="headerRowCheckBox_Checked"                                                  
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedToPrint,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="UPC / PLU"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          Width="140"
                          Binding="{Binding upc}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                          Width="400"
                          Binding="{Binding description}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty To Print"
                          Width="130"
                          Binding="{Binding qty_to_print}"/>

      <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty To Print"
                          Width="80"
                          Binding="{Binding qty_printed}"/>-->
  </DataGrid.Columns>

   private void CheckBoxCheckAll_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       PrintLabelViewModel.ToggleCheckUncheck(true);
       Debug.WriteLine("Checked all" + PrintLabelViewModel.PrintLabelCollection.Count);
       //ForceDataGridRefresh();
   }

   private void CheckBoxCheckAll_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       PrintLabelViewModel.ToggleCheckUncheck(false);
       //ForceDataGridRefresh();
   }

   #endregion

   private void headerRowCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (PrintLabelViewModel.PrintLabelCollection.All(p => !p.IsSelectedToPrint))
       {
           PrintLabelViewModel.IsCheckAll = false;
           //ForceDataGridRefresh();
       }
   }

   private void headerRowCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (PrintLabelViewModel.PrintLabelCollection.All(p => p.IsSelectedToPrint))
       {
           PrintLabelViewModel.IsCheckAll = true;
           //ForceDataGridRefresh();
       }
   }

   //private void ForceDataGridRefresh()
   //{
   //    // Assuming your DataGrid is named "dataGrid"
   //    var dataGrid = FindName("displayDataGrid") as DataGrid;
   //    if (dataGrid != null)
   //    {
   //        dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
   //        //var temp = dataGrid.ItemsSource;
   //        //dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
   //        //dataGrid.ItemsSource = temp;
   //    }
   //}

Please note the ForceDataRefresh code as well as triggers that I tried to fix the issue only caused an empty data grid.
EDIT:
The PrintLabelViewModel is quite large : here is the areas, please advise if more is needed
   public class PrintLabelViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
       #region Variables

       private Window _ownerWindow;
       private DymoLabels dymoLabels;
       private DymoAddIn dymoAddIn;
       private string labelPath = string.Empty;

       string tmpDeptHashId = string.Empty,
           productId = string.Empty,
           categoryId = string.Empty,
           manufacturerId = string.Empty,
           brandId = string.Empty;

       string deptName = string.Empty,
           categoryName = string.Empty,
           manufacturerName = string.Empty,
           brandName = string.Empty;

       private string category1 = string.Empty,
           category2 = string.Empty,
           category3 = string.Empty,
           category4 = string.Empty;

       #endregion

       #region Constructor

       /// <summary>
       /// Initialize notification type list and all button command initialization with handle execute methods
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="ownerWin"></param>
       public PrintLabelViewModel(Window ownerWin)
       {
           _ownerWindow = ownerWin;
           PrinterList = new ObservableCollection<CommonDict>();
           FormatList = new ObservableCollection<CommonDict>();
           PriceTypeList = new ObservableCollection<CommonDict>();
           RefreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(RefreshExecute);
           PrintCommand = new DelegateCommand(PrintExecute);
           CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(CloseExecute);
           ManufacturerCollection = new ObservableCollection<CommonDictList>();
           BrandCollection = new ObservableCollection<CommonDict>();
           VendorCollection = new ObservableCollection<CommonDict>();

           LoadLabelTemplates();
           BindPrinters();
           BindPriceTypes();
           BindVendors();

           DymoSDK.App.Init();
           dymoSDKLabel = DymoLabel.Instance;
           labelPath = FileSystemHelper.DymoLabelTemplateFolder;
       }

       #endregion

       #region Properties

       private ObservableCollection<CommonDict> printerList;

       public ObservableCollection<CommonDict> PrinterList
       {
           get { return printerList; }
           set
           {
               if (printerList != value)
               {
                   printerList = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("PrinterList");
               }
           }
       }

       private ObservableCollection<PrintLabel> printLabelCollection;

       public ObservableCollection<PrintLabel> PrintLabelCollection
       {
           get { return printLabelCollection; }
           set
           {
               if (printLabelCollection != value)
               {
                   printLabelCollection = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("PrintLabelCollection");
               }
           }
       }

       private PrintLabel selectedPrintLabel;

       public PrintLabel SelectedPrintLabel
       {
           get { return selectedPrintLabel; }
           set
           {
               if (selectedPrintLabel != value)
               {
                   selectedPrintLabel = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPrintLabel");
               }
           }
       }

       private CommonDict selectedPrinter;

       public CommonDict SelectedPrinter
       {
           get { return selectedPrinter; }
           set
           {
               if (selectedPrinter != value)
               {
                   selectedPrinter = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPrinter");
                   LoadLabelTemplates();
               }
           }
       }

       private CommonDict selectedPriceType;

       public CommonDict SelectedPriceType
       {
           get { return selectedPriceType; }
           set
           {
               if (selectedPriceType != value)
               {
                   selectedPriceType = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPriceType");
               }
           }
       }

       private ObservableCollection<CommonDict> priceTypeList;

       public ObservableCollection<CommonDict> PriceTypeList
       {
           get { return priceTypeList; }
           set
           {
               if (priceTypeList != value)
               {
                   priceTypeList = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("PriceTypeList");
               }
           }
       }

       private ObservableCollection<CommonDict> formatList;

       public ObservableCollection<CommonDict> FormatList
       {
           get { return formatList; }
           set
           {
               if (formatList != value)
               {
                   formatList = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("FormatList");
               }
           }
       }

       private CommonDict selectedFormat;

       public CommonDict SelectedFormat
       {
           get { return selectedFormat; }
           set
           {
               if (selectedFormat != value)
               {
                   selectedFormat = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFormat");
               }
           }
       }

       private ObservableCollection<CommonDictList> manufacturerCollection;

       public ObservableCollection<CommonDictList> ManufacturerCollection
       {
           get { return manufacturerCollection; }
           set
           {
               if (manufacturerCollection != value)
               {
                   manufacturerCollection = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("ManufactureCollection");
               }
           }
       }

       private ObservableCollection<CommonDict> brandCollection;

       public ObservableCollection<CommonDict> BrandCollection
       {
           get { return brandCollection; }
           set
           {
               if (brandCollection != value)
               {
                   brandCollection = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("BrandCollection");
               }
           }
       }

       private ObservableCollection<CommonDict> vendorCollection;

       public ObservableCollection<CommonDict> VendorCollection
       {
           get { return vendorCollection; }
           set
           {
               if (vendorCollection != value)
               {
                   vendorCollection = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("VendorCollection)");
               }
           }
       }

       private CommonDict selectedVendor;

       public CommonDict SelectedVendor
       {
           get { return selectedVendor; }
           set
           {
               if (selectedVendor != value)
               {
                   selectedVendor = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedVendor");
                   //UpdateVendorInfo(value.Key);
               }
           }
       }

       private bool includeBuydown;

       public bool IncludeBuydown
       {
           get { return includeBuydown; }
           set
           {
               if (includeBuydown != value)
               {
                   includeBuydown = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("IncludeBuydown");
               }
           }
       }

       private bool includeDiscount;

       public bool IncludeDiscount
       {
           get { return includeDiscount; }
           set
           {
               if (includeDiscount != value)
               {
                   includeDiscount = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("IncludeDiscount");
               }
           }
       }

       private bool isCheckAll;

       public bool IsCheckAll
       {
           get { return isCheckAll; }
           set
           {
               if (isCheckAll != value)
               {
                   isCheckAll = value;
                   RaisePropertyChanged("IsCheckAll");
               }
           }
       }


Can you update your question with PrintLabelViewModel?

The PrintLabelViewModel is quite large, I edited with the top of code block that deals with the CheckAll and Observable collection.  Please advise if you require more.
Thanks!

The answer here is a good resource.


You don't need the code-behind event handlers for the Checked and Unchecked events.  Get rid of them.  2. Instead, when the view-model's IsCheckAll property changes (will happen when the user checks the box), right there you should go through each and every item in the PrintLabelCollection and change its IsSelectedToPrint property.  When the IsSelectedToPrint property changes and you raise PropertyChanged, WPF will update the UI.  3. Make sure that both classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged correctly and fire the event when those properties change.  WPF will do the rest.


Sometimes it's just simpler to add "only" a Click even to the CheckBox, and test "IsChecked" in the Click event.

Thanks for the advice all!  I found the issue. It was a graphic update issue in the DataGrid.  I was able to update the graphics and NOT the data at check all and uncheck all:  I couldn't simplify it because of requirements for the project :
        private void ForceVisualUpdate()
    {
        // Optionally refresh the view
        var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(LabelDataGrid.ItemsSource);
        collectionView?.Refresh();

        // Force update layout
        LabelDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
    }

        private void CheckBoxCheckAll_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintLabelViewModel.ToggleCheckUncheck(true);
        ForceVisualUpdate(); // Force visual update
    }

    private void CheckBoxCheckAll_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintLabelViewModel.ToggleCheckUncheck(false);
        ForceVisualUpdate(); // Force visual update
    }

after stress testing that is handling over 100 items in the DataGrid instantly.
